# if(something) vs if(something===true)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I was doing some self-learning about cakephp (version 1.26).
I got a simple HTML input text field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data[testing][name]" id="data[testing][name]">
```

The value from the Input text box field was checked against the database.
If the value matches the data stored in the database, it will return true.
Here is the code:

```
{
  $t=$this->data;
  $result=$this->User->findByname($t['testing']['name']); 
  if($result){ //doing something;}
}
```

I came across a question when I altered the code above with a little change, 
but then it failed to work then:

```
 {
      $t=$this->data;
      $result=$this->User->findByname($t['testing']['name']); 
      if($result===true){ //doing something;}
    }
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming here that findByName returns some kind of object or array. if you use `if ($result)` this object/array will be cast to a boolean.

If however you use `if ($result === true)` you're strictly comparing an object/array to the boolean `true`, this comparison will always evaluate to false.

Answer (score 7):

You are using ***strict*** type comparison with `===` rather than `==`, this implies that `$result` is actually not equal to `true` there by making the condition fail. Try to see what does come though in the `$result` variable:

```
var_dump($result);
```

Or try this condition with (`==`):

```
if($result == true){ //doing something;}
```

Or simply:

```
if ($this->User->findByname($t['testing']['name'])){ //doing something;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP reference has a very nice explanation of how type comparison is done. The quick answer is that you are now doing a much stricter comparison, and some edge cases are falling through the cracks. You will probably be fine with $result == true

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$result === true` checks, if `$result` value is `true`.
But your `$result` variable contains results from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Coarsely, the `if` operator [casts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) your argument into a boolean and evaluates it. So `if($result)` converts `$result` into `true` or `false`. On the other hand, `===` actually checks for both type and "value" equality, so `true === $val` will only return `true` if `$val` is the boolean `true`. `===` obviously returns a boolean, so no casting is necessary for the subsequent evaluation within `if`. What this means for you is that `if($result)` processes the block if `$result` casts into `true`. Examples of things that become `true` are `1`, `'1'`, and `new Object()`. Conversely, `if($result===true)` doesn't immediately cast `$result`. It checks it in type and "value" against boolean `true`.

If `$result` is, say `1`, the former control structure will process the block, but the latter won't.

Comment: By the way, this issue has essentially nothing to do with CakePHP. `===` and `if` are both native PHP operators.

Answer (score 1):

=== means equal AND the same type of what you equaling to...
but $result contains data from db..so it's not Boolean...
use == instead:

```
if($result==true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when there is a result, the return is non-zero, therefore it will evaluate to `true`.

=== is the identity operator and will return `true` when the two objects are **identical**

e.g. `1===1 (true) true===true (true) true===1` (**false**)

== is the equality operator and will return `true` when the two objects are **equal** or **equivalent**.

e.g. `1==1 (true) true==true (true) true==1` (**true**)

**findByName** will return an array or `unset`. `unset` will equate to `false` and an array will equate to `true`.

the value `true` itself is never returned in your code, so === will never be `true`.